# Integración Redsys in-site en front-end

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo pruebas para empezar a implementar la pasarela de pago Redsys en su modalidad 'in-site':
https://pagosonline.redsys.es/conexion-insite.html#pasos-pagina

Según la documentación oficial si se desea la integración 'unificada' (ya incluye los elementos del formulario), no se requieren más acciones que las que estoy empleando:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/NC/sandbox/redsysV2.js"></script>
 
</head>

<body onload="loadRedsysForm()">
    <div id="card-form"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="token" ></input>
    <input type="hidden" id="errorCode" ></input>
     <script>   
        function merchantValidationEjemplo(){
            //Insertar validaciones…
            return true;
        }
                    

        <!-- Listener de recepción de ID de operación -->
        window.addEventListener("message", function receiveMessage(event) {
            storeIdOper(event,"token", "errorCode", "merchantValidationEjemplo");
        });
        getInSiteForm('card-form', estiloBody, estiloCaja, estiloInputs, 'Pagar con redsys', fuc, terminal, merchantOrder);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Con esto creo que debería ser suficiente para que me 'pinte' el formulario de pago en la página, sin embargo no lo hace.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Algunas cosas:

1. Hay que inicializar y asignar valor las variables que pasamos a getInsiteForm (bastante obvio, pero no está en la documentación oficial). Fuc, terminal y merchantOrder deben ser algunos de los que Redsys facilita para test.
2. Hay que ejecutar la página en un servidor local. Lo explico en: [Integración pasarela de pago Redys modalidad InSite](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/415434/integraci%c3%b3n-pasarela-de-pago-redys-modalidad-insite)
   donde también incluyo el código con las modificaciones del punto anterior. Tras eso el iframe carga correctamente, aunque solo en localhost como explico en esa pregunta.