# Integrar Redsys pagos online insite

Tags: php, json

Estoy intentando instalar el insite de pagos online Redsys, y sinceramente no encuentro buenos ejemplos y su Faq deja mucho de desear. No uso plataformas.

He intentado seguir las instrucciones de Redsys y nisiquiera consigo imprimir el iframe.
En este enlace un miembro comenta el mismo problema:
[Integración pasarela de pago Redys modalidad InSite](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/415434/integraci%c3%b3n-pasarela-de-pago-redys-modalidad-insite/463879#463879)

Lo que si me he dado cuenta es que este miembre usa esto en su codigo y dice que es de sus instrucciones:

```
getInSiteForm('card-form', estiloBoton, estiloBody, estiloCaja, estiloInputs, 'Aceptar',
    '999008881', '1', 'F8OYDISB16DA','1');
```

Si ejecuto el codigo de este miembro me sale que Redsys no acepta la conexión.
Lo cierto es que las instrucciones de Redsys no viene ahora con tantas variables, ahora solo viene 4, esto pone en las instrucciones:

```
getInSiteForm('card-form', estiloBoton, estiloBody, estiloCaja, estiloInputs, 'Texto botón pago', fuc, terminal, merchantOrder);
```

Si ejecuto el codigo de las instrucciones no pasa absolutamente nada, una pagina en blanco.

Alguna idea o sugerencia?

Comment: Algún mensaje en la consola del navegador? Es difícil adivinar qué pasa con la API del proveedor... si los contactas por email, te dicen algo?

Comment: Es todo muy raro, si cambio el ficher javascript por el que viene en este manual que encontré por alli funciona: https://www.bbva.es/eng/estaticos/mult/Manual_de_instalacion_para_el_desarrollador_Entrada_REST_Version.pdf

Eso si, si cambio el fuc por el mio deja de funcionar.

Comment: "Deja de funcionar" ?= no pasa nada, sale algún error en la consola del navegador, sale algún error en los logs de PHP? Algo?

Comment: Les he escrito un email y me han contestado: "Atendiendo a su consulta, informarle que en la integración insite se necesita autoriza la url para que se muestre el iframe, dentro de la configuración del tpvv en comercio, datos de configuración, hay un apartado que se llamada dominios insite permitidos, en pruebas podemos autorizar su url pero en real tiene que solicitárselo al gestor de su entidad bancaria. Por favor confírmenos que url quiere que autoricemos para que se muestre el iframe"

No entiendo como no lo hayan dicho desde principio

Answer (score 0):

En mi reciente y sufrida experiencia, respecto a cuanto planteas he podido comprobar lo siguiente:

1. Lo que dices en tu comentario es totalmente cierto: hay que pedirles que habiliten los dominios requeridos para pruebas pero solamente si eres cliente (es decir si tienes un **FUC** válido).
2. En desarrollo, se pueden realizar algunas pruebas (al menos he conseguido que me pintara el `iframe`) pero solamente si nuestro servidos de desarrollo tiene los sigientes dominios:

- http://127.0.0.1
- http://localhost:1337
- http://127.0.0.1:8085
- http://localhost:8012
- http://localhost:8000
- http://127.0.0.1:8000
- https://pae-ya.eu *
- file://*

3. Y por si a alguien le puede resultar útil, para el entorno de pruebas he utilizado lo siguiente (el `merchantOrder` es variable):

```
getInSiteForm('card-form', '', '', '', '', 'Aceptar', '999008881', '001', 'Order00123', 'ES', true);
```